# Location to store application specific hidden files without need for administrator privilege

Tags: macos, permission, administrator

I have a software application that I am porting to MacOS. It is normally a Linux based app. There are application specific files required for the software to run correctly that I want hidden from the end user. This is done on Linux in the `.config` folder. This was also done on the port but the issue is that the user needs administrator privileges in order to write to that location. Since the software does just that, this is a problem. I am looking for a solution to that, whether it be another - preferably hidden - location that I can use instead, or some other means of making that folder writeable without the need for administrative privilege. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly is the `.config` folder you’re trying to write to?

Comment: @Allan, It is in the users home directory.

Comment: If it is the home directory, then the user can create hidden (any type, actually) folders\files.  Make sure the folder is created and owned by the user.

Comment: Yeah, that's not how this works. The application is installed by the user. You can't ask them to create a folder chain prior to install so the application works. That's very silly.

Comment: The app can create the folder so long as it’s run by the user.  If it runs as root, you then need to change ownership/permissions (by script)  to give the user full rights.